# Split function in js

Tags: javascript, java

I am using split function in javascript that will split arraylist coming from java on the basis of comma. But I am facing an issue where words having comma are splitted into two separated words. How do I overcome this problem.

Example-

["Technology Science", "Maths", "Fundamental,Theory of computation"]

Output using split (,) in js:-

"Technology Science", "Maths", "Fundamental","Theory of computation"

Expected:-

"Technology Science", "Maths", "Fundamental,Theory of computation"

Comment: The split method only works with arrays. And in this case, I can see the initial;y provided data is an array itself so, you can't use split in that case.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Are you getting a string, or a JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

You can split on `", "`, assuring that the initial `"` is not escaped.

```
(?<!\\)\", \"
```

Answer (score 0):

That format is coincidentally compatible with JSON.  Because of that, you can use:

```
let titles=JSON.parse(arraylistOutput);
```